# MS Access loop query for every row on a table

Tags: ms-access

I'm not very experienced with MS Access and I'm trying to loop through every record on a table (tbl_jobs_main) and run this query against it.

```
SELECT division.[Department]
FROM division
WHERE tbl_jobs_main.[org1] = division.[ORG1];
```

My hope is that the new column "Department" in the tbl_jobs_main table can be auto filled from the division table with the Department values by matching the ORG1 values for each row. To clarify, the ORG1 values in the division table are unique and the org1 values in tbl_jobs_main are duplicated.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

(Sorry, not enough rep to post images on this profile.)
Example data in Division table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYDh3.png

Example data in tbl_jobs_main table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIel9.png

I need for the Department column to populate with the corresponding Department in the Division table based on the matching ORG1 value. 
Ideally I could run something so the tbl_jobs_main becomes this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU1ko.png

Comment: What do you mean by *auto filled*? Do you want to update the table tbl_jobs_main? Post sample data and expected results and clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst you can loop through `tbl_jobs_main` and update the Department based on data in the `Division` table, you can also use an update Query. The SQL will look like:

```
UPDATE tbl_jobs_main AS J INNER JOIN Division AS D 
ON D.Org1=J.Org1
SET J.Department=D.Department
```

However, I am not sure why you would want to do this. If the name of "Dept1" in the `division` table changes, you then have to re-update `tbl_jobs_main` to reflect this. Far better to use Access as a relational database, where you store the department information in the `Division` table, and link the tables.

Regards,